# Real analysis, limit points ,basics

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $S= \{(-1)^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
has two limit points $-1$ and $1$.

How can set $S$ possess limit point since Set $S ={-1,1,-1,1....}$? It has $-1$ and $1$ as its element if $-1$ is its limit point then $(-1-\epsilon ,-1+ \epsilon)$ intersection $S -\{-1\}$ should have infinitely many points but that's not the case.

Comment: No. That's not true. Let 1 be limit point. Now every deleted neighborhood of 1 should contain atleast one element of S. If you consider then neibourhood as ${x: 0\lt |x-1|\lt 2}$, then it does not contain any element of S-{1}.

Comment: Thats false, they are adherent but not limit points

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by “limit point” and how you interpret the notation.

If $S$ is a *sequence*, namely the sequence $n\mapsto(-1)^n$, then certainly $1$ and $-1$ are limit points in the sense of the following definition

> a point $p$ is called a limit point (or a cluster point) of the sequence $n\mapsto a_n$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and every $k$ there exists $n>k$ with $a_n\in U$.

In other words, a limit (or cluster) point is one such that a subsequence converges to.

If you consider $S$ as a set, then it has no limit points, because it's finite.